# My first Google App Engine/Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I am trying to write my first GAE/Python application that does the following three things:

1. Displays a form where the user can enter details about themself (index.html)
2. Stores the submitted form data in the datastore
3. Retrieves all data from datastore and displays all results above the form (index.html)

However, I'm getting the following error

> line 15, in MainPage 'people' : people NameError: name 'people' is not
>   defined

Any advice on how to resolve this and get my app working will be appreciated!

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        people_query = Person.all()
        people = people_query.fetch(10)

    template_values = {
        'people': people
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

# retrieve the submitted form data and store in datastore   
class PeopleStore(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        person = Person()
        person.first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
        person.last_name = self.request.get('last_name')
        person.city = self.request.get('city')
        person.birth_year = self.request.get('birth_year')
        person.birth_year = self.request.get('height')
        person.put()        

# models a person class 
class Person(db.Model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    city = db.StringProperty()
    birth_year = db.IntegerProperty()
    height = db.IntegerProperty()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_person')], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% for person in people %}
            {% if person %}
                <b>{{ person.first_name }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.last_name }}</b>
                <b>{{ person.city }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.birth_year }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.height }}</b> 
                <hr></hr>
            {% else %}
                No people found         
        {% endfor %}

        <form action="/new_person" method="post">           
            <div><textarea name="first_name" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="last_name" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="city" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="birth_year" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="height" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>         
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: some_name
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

---

**EDIT 1**
**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        people_query = Person.all()
        people = people_query.fetch(10)

        template_values = {
            'people': people
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class PeopleStore(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        person = Person()
        person.first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
        person.last_name = self.request.get('last_name')
        person.city = self.request.get('city')
        person.birth_year = self.request.get('birth_year')
        person.height = self.request.get('height')
        person.put()        


class Person(db.Model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    city = db.StringProperty()
    birth_year = db.IntegerProperty()
    height = db.IntegerProperty()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_person')], debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT 2**
**main.py**

The following edit fixed this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_match_routes'

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/new_person',PeopleStore)], debug=True)
```

Ok great, the form displays in the browser, but when I submit the data, I get this error:

> BadValueError: Property birth_year must be an int or long, not a
>   unicode

---

**EDIT 3
main.py**

```
person.birth_year = int(self.request.get('birth_year'))
person.height = int(self.request.get('height'))
```

resolved this error:

> badvalueerror property must be an int or long, not a unicode

Ok, good so far. The data stores in the data store. However, my page comes up blank...

Comment: Daniel answered your question, but I just noticed that you are setting the `birth_year` twice in your sample; once its the birth year, and the second time its being overwritten with the height.

Comment: +1 ohhh thanks! I'll fix it in EDIT 1 above.

Comment: The indentation error is resolved. However, I'm getting another error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_match_routes'. Does that have to do with a missing route in app.yaml file?

Comment: I left out PeopleStore in my handler (see Edit 2 above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation problem. Lines 3 and onwards of your `get` method should be indented at the same level as the first two lines. Otherwise, they are not part of the method, but the class definition itself, and will be executed when the class is defined - at which point there is no variable `people` in scope.

Comment: +1 thanks for your reply. I fixed the indent problem (see EDIT 1). Now I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_match_routes'

Comment: I left out PeopleStore in my handler: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_person')], debug=True).

Answer (score 1):

In your app.yaml it doesnt like the underscore

```
#application: some_name
application: somename
```

There are some more issues with blocks not being closed etc which you need to work through yourself